# Angularjs 1 - one request, multiple responses

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with multiple widgets, each receiving data from a different query in the backend. Doing a request for each will consume the limit the browser puts on the number of parallel connections and will serialize some of them. On the other hand, doing one request that will return one response means it will be as slow as the slowest query (I have no apriori knowledge about which query will be slowest).

So I want to create one request such that the backend runs the queries in parallel and writes each result as it is ready and for the frontend to handle each result as it arrives. At the HTTP level I believe it can be just one body with serveral json, or maybe multipart response.

Is there an angularjs extension that handles the frontend side of things? Optimally something that works well with whatever can be done in the Java backend (didn't start investigating my options there)

Comment: you can look into `$q.all()`. [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all), also [this](https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q)

Comment: `angularjs` is for Angular1, `angular` is for Angular2. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Mistalis Fixed, Thanks

Comment: @anoop I'm trying to achieve the reverse. I don't want to send multiple requests and wait for all of them to finish. I want to send one request and handle partial response data as it arrives

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to my mind is using WebSockets. This way you can send one void request to backend and backend will push data to your front via WebSocket. Not sure if it'll benefit in speed by any way.

Comment: @Kindzoku, websockets is an overkill and will make the server side more complex (e.g. need to integrate with a web sockets library instead of using Servlets 3.0 async support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/dfltr/jQuery-MXHR

This plugin allows to parse a response that contains several parts (multipart) by having a callback to parse each part. This can be used in all our frontends to support responses for multiple data (widgets) in one requests. The server side will receive one request and use servlet 3 async support (or whatever exists in other languages) to ‘park’ it, sending multiple queries, writing each response to the request as each query returns (and with the right multipart boundary).

Another example can be found here: https://github.com/anentropic/stream.
While both of these may not be compatible with angularjs, the code does not seem complex to port there.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion to solve your problem, but I am not sure you would be able to implement such a thing as from you question it is not very clear what you can or cannot do.

You could implement WebSockets and the server would be able to notify the front-end about the data being fetched or it could send the data via WebSockets right away.

In the first example, you would send a request to the server to fetch all the data for your dashboard. Once a piece of data is available, you could make a request for that particular piece and given that the data was fetched couple of seconds ago, it could be cached on the server and the response would be fast.

The second approach seems a more reasonable one. You would make an HTTP/WebSocket request to the server and wait for the data to arrive over WebSocket.

I believe this would be the most robust an efficient way to implement what you are asking for.

Comment: Sure this can be done with websockets, but it creates a more complex protocol and requires a more complex server side handling.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Unfortunately I am not aware of any other solution to this particular problem.